# Bicycle Transport Venice Airport

Tags: air-travel, luggage, airports, bicycles, venice

We (2 people) are traveling to Venice by bike and we plan to fly back from Marco Polo Airport. We will stay in Venice for a couple of days after. We will park the bike in the San Marco Bike garage (because bikes are not allowed in Venice).

Before leaving, we need to put the bikes into a box according to the regulations of the flight company. We thought about buying the boxes in Mestre in the morning.

What is the most convenient way of transport the packaged bike between Mestre and Marco Polo?

Any other tips regarding bike transport from Marco Polo Airport are appreciated.

Comment: For information, here are the [official rules for cycling in Venice in English](https://www.comune.venezia.it/en/content/venice-and-bycicles).